# how to change notification to another when clicked- android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, notificationmanager

My app is for display a notification which is much like a reminder. So far, I can display my text on the notification box. But I want it to switch to another notification when user clicks on it.

here is my code: `else{

```
  Text = "go to shopping mall";
  Text2 = "meet emma";
 final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0.getContext(), 0, new         Intent(arg0.getContext(),MainActivity.class), 0);
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

    public Void doInBackground(Void... args){


        Bitmap bmp = BimapFactory.decodeResource(arg0.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0.getContext())
         .setContentTitle("I want to...")
         .setContentText(Text)
         .setContentIntent(pending)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
             .bigPicture(bmp))
         .build();
        notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)arg0.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationmanager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        notificationId++;
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

`

**This works exactly how I wanted. But I want to display **Text2*** when user clicks on the notification.*

**Note:**For now, when I click on this notification,it brings me to the application itself, which is intended. But this should now only change the text, without taking me somewhere else.

Please, consider re-edit my code to explain,if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` as a click listener, changing your action `PendingIntent` to point to it, and [updating](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating) your `Notification` with the new text from the `BroadcastReceiver` callback.

Comment: am very new to android app development. Can you please tell me where to start for learning broadcastReceiver? and **changing your action PendingIntent to point it** you meant that I should call the broadcastReceiver as the pending intent(I mean the second intent to lunch)??

Comment: @androCoder-BD: You can read about `BroadcastReceiver` in the [reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Yes, you should use the `getBroadcast()` method to create a `PendingIntent` and supply the `Intent` to start your `BroadcastReceiver` instead of the `Activity`.